# Securepay payment gateway integration issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography, payment-gateway, sha

I am working on Securepay Integration with my ASP.NET web page, as per their documentation I am generating SHA1 from following information:

The Fingerprint is a SHA1 hash of the above fields plus the SecurePay Transaction Password in this order with a pipe separator “|”:

1. EPS_MERCHANTID
2. Transaction Password (supplied by SecurePay Support)
3. EPS_TXNTYPE (as 0)
4. EPS_REFERENCEID (for testing purpose 123)
5. EPS_AMOUNT (for testing purpose 100.00)
6. EPS_TIMESTAMP (for testing purpose 20120910203805)

Though I have followed above given instruction but whenever I am doing payment it says "***Invalid Fingerprint***". Example code:

```
FormsAuthentication
  .HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile("xxx|xxx|0|123|100.00|201‌20910203805","sha1")
  .ToLower();`
```

Comment: Please can you show your code (with secrets masked)

Comment: Ok, it is as follow: FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile("xxx|xxx|0|123|100.00|20120910203805", "sha1").ToLower();

Comment: So you are using this to create a hash-password to be saved in a config file? Just asking because the docs say it is suitable for storing in the configs.

Comment: I am not using a hash-password to be saved in config file but above given function creates the SHA1 without storing it

Comment: I think you need to read the documentation closer around how to hash because I am thinking you are wanting a secure hash to send in with the request so that they (the payment service provider) can verify your request is from you? Usually you have a shared secret word which gets hashed in with the other bits of information.

Comment: Also, are you sure this is the right class to use for this, it doesn't feel right because the method name seems to imply it is used for a different purpose?

Comment: I have checked it further and found that SHA1 given by example from Servicepay and created by above code both are not matching. It is differing. I have used this FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile("ABC0010|txnpassword|0|Test Reference|1.00|20110616221931", "sha1").ToLower();  and I have SHA1 as "7871d5c9a366339da848fc64cb32f6a9ad8fcadd" and "01a1edbb159aa01b99740508d79620251c2f871d" this is suggested by Securepay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are ending the line correctly, either with a trailing '|' or removing unnecessary trailing '|'.

Also check that the method you are using doesn't add anything else inside the method that would distort what you are expecting. (I am thinking a salt based upon the particular machine you are on don't know if it does this or not)

I have been attempting to generate a hash here http://shagenerator.com/ using this:

```
ABC|password|1|Te‌​st Reference|1.00|20120912123421
```

gives:

```
25a1804285bafc078f45e41056bcdc42e0508b6f
```

Can you get the same key with your code using my input?

Update:

Can you try this method instead of `HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile()` and see if you get closer:

```
private string GetSHA1String(string text)
{
    var UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
    var message = UE.GetBytes(text);

    var hashString = new SHA1Managed(); 
    var hex = string.Empty;

    var hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message); 
    foreach (byte b in hashValue)
    { 
        hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", b);
    } 

    return hex;
}
```

UPDATE 2:

**Check your encoding, I discovered that I can match the hash output with:**

```
var UE = new UTF8Encoding();
```

UPDATE 3:

The following code worked for me in a console app, I was seeing the hashes generate the same value and I was able to compare the output to http://shagenerator.com/ also:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace SecurepayPaymentGatewayIntegrationIssue
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = @"ABC|password|1|Te‌​st Reference|1.00|20120912123421";
            Console.WriteLine(GetSHA1String(text));

            Console.WriteLine(FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(text, "sha1").ToLower());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static string GetSHA1String(string text)
        {
            var UE = new UTF8Encoding();// ASCIIEncoding(); // UnicodeEncoding();
            var message = UE.GetBytes(text);

            var hashString = new SHA1Managed();
            var hex = string.Empty;

            var hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);
            foreach (byte b in hashValue)
            {
                hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", b);
            }

            return hex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried with your input and I got SHA1 as : c09e1bf5f6c201d7dfb3574305458d48f9714a05 which is different to your above given code

Comment: Please show more of your code then as this hashing code I have provided does work, so the problem lies before or after the hashing call.

Comment: Hi Monkieboy, thanks alot for your assistance it has worked fine.

Comment: Have you fixed your problem, if so don't forget to mark this as the answer.

Comment: It has fixed for live URL for Secure pay but for test URL of Secure Pay still shows same old error "Invalid Fingerprint".

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and i solved this using below method:

```
 private string GetSHA1HashData(string data)
        {   

            SHA1 sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

            //convert the input text to array of bytes
            byte[] hashData = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data));

            //create new instance of StringBuilder to save hashed data
            StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder();

            //loop for each byte and add it to StringBuilder
            for (int i = 0; i < hashData.Length; i++)
            {                
                returnValue.Append(hashData[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            // return hexadecimal string
            return returnValue.ToString();
        }
```

In page load I Converted this return value into lower case. because the above method return value with upper case

```
string VAL="ABC|password|1|Te‌​st Reference|1.00|20120912123421";
fingerPrint = GetSHA1HashData(VAL);
```

Comment: 1) Default encoding is certainly not the right idea here since it differers depending on the computer you're running from. Use a fixed encoding instead. I'd expect UTF-8 to be the best choice. 2) I recommend splitting the hash encoding out of `GetSHA1HashData`. (single responsibility principle) 3) The `Trim` is useless, there won't be any spaces in the output in the first place. 4) Instead of `ToLowerInvariant` you could use `ToString("x2")`. 5) the comment "create new instance of md5" does not fit the code. 6) You should dispose `sha1`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks for the info. i did changes u mentioned. but in my scenario i have to use Default encoding, because its mentioned to use.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the time as UTC Now: 
`string epsTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(@"yyyyMMddHHmmss");`

And also make sure you have used sha1 for encryption:

```
string data = EpsMerchant + "|" + EpsPassword + "|" + EpsTxnType + "|" + 
EpsReferenceId + "|" + EpsAmount + "|" + epsTimestamp;
string epsFingerprint = GetSha1String(data);
```

And below is the code for getting sha1

```
string GetSha1String(string input)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in GetHash(input))
                stringBuilder.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

    public static byte[] GetHash(string inputString)
    {
        HashAlgorithm obj = SHA1.Create();
        return obj.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
    }
```